# What is the meaning/role of the -ine suffix?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-meaning

What does the suffix "-ine" mean? How it modifies the meaning of the root word?

Examples:

- medicine
- caffeine
- bovine

Comment: It looks like a typo for *in*.  More context might help, but *\*back ine* isn't English, as far as I know.

Comment: @snailplane I thought that, but as I didn't know the meaning I couldn't decide correctly. BTW, would you please bring some example of correct use of this word?

Comment: @mok It's not a word - it's a very rarely used suffix, borrowed from French.

Comment: @StoneyB: does it somehow have a meaning like -ish?

Comment: @mok Outside of chemistry, it's the French feminine version of the Latin suffix *-inus, -ina, -inum* meaning approximately *of the nature of*: *medicine*, pertaining to a *medicus*, a doctor. It had a vogue for a while in brand names: *Brilliantine*, *Ovaltine*.

Comment: It is also found in words like porcine, bovine, equine, etc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some kind of transcription error, not a normal or valid English usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree, but maybe this is useful for some future reviewers, so I edit the question. So StoneyB and Jim can post their comments as answers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers not a typo!

Comment: @mok be happy, it's not a typo or error! It's a **valid** suffix!

Comment: @Maulik: The question has been completely changed since I cast that original closevote. It's now Off Topic because it's General Reference, but unlike the OP I can't just alter my past actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suffix *-ine* for adjectives has a Greek or Latin origin. [Reference Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ine) mentions it.

> *-ine* -a suffix means “of or pertaining to,” “of the nature of,” “made of,” “like”: asinine; crystalline; equine; marine.

Furthermore, the suffix *-ine* for nouns has Greek, Latin or **French** origin. Explained on the same page of RD.

> *-ine* - a suffix, of no assignable meaning, appearing in nouns of Greek, Latin, or French origin: doctrine; famine; routine.